# Can't get ng-model on $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying new things with AngularJS but I can't get a simple input value.

HTML:

```
<label class="item-input-wrapper">
    <i class="icon ion-ios7-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-change="search()" ng-model="searchText" ng-init="searchText='demo'">
</label>
```

JS:

```
.controller('MoviesCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, lubTmdbApi) {
    console.log("SearchText:"+$scope.searchText)
    $scope.search = function() {
        console.log("SearchText:"+$scope.searchText)
    };
})
```

Always getting:

```
SearchText:undefined
```

UPDATE: this is my State

```
      .state('app.movies', {
            url: "/movies",
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: "templates/movies.html",
                    controller: "MoviesCtrl"
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Show us more code. Where is your ng-controller directive?

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is with the `ng-init` directive.  I removed it and added one line to the controller and everything works now for me.  I recommend wrapping your `ng-model` values inside of an object (I have heard this is for inheritance).

HTML:

```
  <div ng-controller="MoviesCtrl">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
        <i class="icon ion-ios7-search placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-change="search()" ng-model="input.searchText" />
    </label>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
.controller('MoviesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.input = {
        searchText: 'demo'
    };

    $scope.search = function() {
        console.log("SearchText:" + $scope.input.searchText)
    };
});
```

[Here is a working CodePen](http://codepen.io/rossmartin/pen/elpqj).

Comment: This is weird, I copy your code but now always show in the console: demo.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/at3yimo3kwxvgl3/Captura%20de%20Tela%202014-05-06%20%C3%A0s%2013.06.08.png

Comment: @PedroMarques Have you [tried out the working demo on CodePen](http://codepen.io/rossmartin/pen/elpqj)?  Remember to take off the `ng-init` directive.